# Use signup firstname in html profile page

Tags: python, django

I would like to show a user's firstname on their profile after they successfully signup and create a profile.

This is what I have tried in my profile.html page

```
<div class="sidebar-block">
  <div class="profile">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="{% static 'second/images/people/110/guy-6.jpg' %}" alt="your picture" class="img-circle width-80" />
    </a>
    <h4 class="text-display-1 margin-none">{{ Mentor.firstname }}</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my models.py file

```
#mentor model
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
...
class Mentor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    linkedin = models.URLField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    phonenumber = models.IntegerField(null=True,unique=True)
```

forms.py

```
class TeacherSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=100)
    firstname = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    lastname = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    phonenumber = forms.IntegerField(required=True)
    linkedin = forms.URLField(max_length=200)

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User

    def save(self, commit=True):
        self.instance.is_teacher = True
        user = super().save()
        mentor = Mentor.objects.create(
            user=user,
            email=self.cleaned_data['email'],
            firstname=self.cleaned_data['firstname'],
            lastname=self.cleaned_data['lastname'],
            phonenumber=self.cleaned_data['phonenumber'],
            linkedin=self.cleaned_data['linkedin']
        )
        return user
```

and teachers(views.py)

```
class TeacherSignUpView(CreateView):
    model = User
    form_class = TeacherSignUpForm
    template_name = 'registration/signup_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['user_type'] = 'teacher'
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
        login(self.request, user)
        return redirect('teachers:app-instructor-dashboard')
```

I know that if I write {{user.username}} I will get the username used to signup but cannot seem to get any other information

**UPDATE**

After making changes suggested by one of the answers this is the code I have now

models.py

```
class Mentor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True)
    linkedin = models.URLField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    phonenumber = models.IntegerField(null=True,unique=True)
```

and forms.py

```
class TeacherSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=100)
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    phonenumber = forms.IntegerField(required=True)
    linkedin = forms.URLField(max_length=200)

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        self.instance.is_teacher = True
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        mentor = Mentor.objects.create(
            user=user,
            phonenumber=self.cleaned_data['phonenumber'],
            linkedin=self.cleaned_data['linkedin']
        )
        return user
```

Now I am getting this error message:

> ValueError at /accounts/signup/teacher/ save() prohibited to prevent
>   data loss due to unsaved related object 'user'.

I am still getting this error even after running

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

Comment: are you using default django User model?

Comment: @engin_ipek I created some custom fields

Comment: Can you share that model too?

Comment: @engin_ipek I think that is the models.py code I shared?

Comment: But the thing is if you really can reach the username attribute, you should be able to reach all others as well. Are you certain you can reach user.username in that view?

Comment: yeah. I can see the username if I add {{user.username}} in my html file

Comment: @engin_ipek you are not referring to class User(AbstractUser) ...the lines I added as an update?

Comment: Oh yes, just seen them sorry

Comment: So you say, user.is_student doesn't work.. by any chance did you forget migrating?

Answer (score 0):

`User` already has first and last names, you can re-use it instead of adding to a new model `Mentor`. Before saving `user` just update these fields like this:

```
user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['firstname']
user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['lastname']
user.save()
```

Full example:

Models:

```
class Mentor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    linkedin = models.URLField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    phonenumber = models.IntegerField(null=True,unique=True)

class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    ...
```

Form:

```
class TeacherSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=100)
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    phonenumber = forms.IntegerField(required=True)
    linkedin = forms.URLField(max_length=200)

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User  # use the model from from django.contrib.auth.models import User
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save()
        mentor = Mentor.objects.create(
            user=user,
            phonenumber=self.cleaned_data['phonenumber'],
            linkedin=self.cleaned_data['linkedin']
        )
        return user
```

Comment: no problem, so I would remove the mentor model (unless I want to add phone number and LinkedIn) and remove the lines of code between class TeacherSignUpForm and class Meta along with the changes you are suggesting?

Comment: This wont fix his problem though

Comment: @Emm yes, you can reuse the fields from the standard `User` model. I updated the answer with a full example. In this case you need to rename `firstname` to `first_name` to avoid mapping, the rest will be done by Django.

Comment: seems to return the error message 'NOT NULL constraint failed: classroom_mentor.email'

Comment: @Emm Most probably you need to re-create and re-run migrations. It complains about `Mentor.email` field which is removed in the new models.

Comment: tried running makemigrations getting this error now -> save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'user'. Added the updated code I have to my initial question